# Trigger a zoom function on a div being shown/concealed.

Tags: css, function, hide, show

I have a function which shows/hides divs on a page. Within these revealed divs is an image and the 'close' button. I'm trying to get this to zoom animate up/down.

I've got a reasonable zoom function but the problem is the zooms all happen on page load, when I need them to be triggered on the div reveal. Any suggestions on what I need to do to achieve it with the code I have (or suggest better ways) would be appreciated.

Thanks

HTML

```
 <div class="box1" id="box1ID" style="display:none;">
    <div class="page_image_wrapper">
    <!--<img src="images/1.png" width="1080" height="1920">-->
    <div id="zoom-box">
<img src="images/13.png" width="1080" height="1920" />
</div>
    </div> 
    <div class="close_box">
    <a href="#" name="1" onclick="conceal('box1ID');">
    <img src="images/transparent.png" width="100" height="100"> 
    </a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Show/Conceal function

```
function conceal(boxId) {      
        if(document.getElementById(boxId).style.display=='block') {
          document.getElementById(boxId).style.display='none';
        }
        return false;
    }  

function show(boxId) {
    if(document.getElementById(boxId).style.display=='none') {
      document.getElementById(boxId).style.display='block';
    }
    return false;
}
```

Zoom-box function:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
$('#zoom-box').animate({
    width:'1080px',
    height:'1920px',
    top:'0',
    left:'0',
    'font-size':'50px',
    'line-height':'300px'
}, 1000);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your zoom in a function and call it after the div is revealed.  I've gone ahead and used jQuery for the show and conceal functions as well since you're already using it for the zoom.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function zoomIn() {
        $('#zoom-box').animate({
            width:'1080px',
            height:'1920px',
            top:'0',
            left:'0',
            'font-size':'50px',
            'line-height':'300px'
        }, 1000);
    }
    function conceal(boxId) {
        $('#' + boxId).hide();
        // You could potentially create a zoomOut function and call it here to 'reset' the zoom
        // zoomOut();
    }
    function show(boxId) {
        $('#' + boxId).show();
        // Call your zoom function here
        zoomIn();
    }
});
```

As noted in the comment, you could also create a zoomOut function to 'reset' the zoom and call it in the conceal function.